# Cannot start vncserver: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, vnc, tightvnc

I use `vnc` over `ssh` with my Raspberry Pi. It has worked fine for a while, but after following [these instructions](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-setup-purevpn-on-raspberry-pi-openvpn) to set up `openvpn` on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian OS. I found that I can no longer access the VNC server on the Raspberry Pi.

Forwarding x11 over `ssh` is working, but apparently, the `vnc server` cannot get access to its port, and so does not even start.

```
$ sudo systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced -l

● vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-01-21 14:25:11 GMT; 1s ago
Main PID: 8896 (vncserver-x11-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
       ├─8896 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
       ├─8898 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service
       └─8913 /usr/bin/vncagent service 14

Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: ConsoleDisplay: Found running X server (pid=1001)
```

There doesn't appear to be anything running on that port. This is the output of `lsof`:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp

COMMAND    PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cupsd      752       root   10u  IPv4  13511      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cups-brow  756       root    5u  IPv4 313573      0t0  TCP localhost:48450->localhost:ipp (CLOSE_WAIT)
dnsmasq    914    dnsmasq    5u  IPv4  11726      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq    914    dnsmasq    7u  IPv6  11728      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
sshd       976       root    3u  IPv4  11842      0t0  TCP *:2718 (LISTEN)
tor        998 debian-tor    4u  IPv4  12125      0t0  TCP 192.168.254.159:49042->ks3352401.kimsufi.com:8090 (ESTABLISHED)
tor        998 debian-tor    7u  IPv4  14489      0t0  TCP localhost:9050 (LISTEN)
tor        998 debian-tor   11u  IPv4  15915      0t0  TCP 172.94.70.220:47186->166.70.170.234:https (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      5550       root    3u  IPv4 315897      0t0  TCP 192.168.254.159:2718->192.168.254.47:64500 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      6322      morey    3u  IPv4 315897      0t0  TCP 192.168.254.159:2718->192.168.254.47:64500 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      6322      morey   10u  IPv4 319584      0t0  TCP localhost:6010 (LISTEN)
```

Here's some other information that might be helpful:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ vncserver --help
VNC(R) Server 6.1.1 (r28093) ARMv6 (May 19 2017 12:59:35)
```

It seems likely this has to do with either the changes to `iptables` or the disabling of ip6 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

`::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`. Thus, if you have disabled IPv6, then yes, listening to `::1` becomes impossible.

You have two options:

- First, and recommended as far as I'm concerned, is to re-enable IPv6. There is no real reason to disable IPv6 in the modern world anymore (in fact, in a few years you may be unable to reach the Internet without IPv6), and it will probably cause more issues than just this one
- Configure `vncserver-x11` so that it no longer tries to listen to `::1`, or any other IPv6 address (`::` would be the most likely other candidate for that).

The `vncserver-x11-serviced` thing appears to be specific to RealVNC, and I can't find any documentation that explains how to configure the listening addresses for it, so you might have to figure the last bit out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not accepting connections: failed to listen on at least one address.
Jan 21 14:25:11 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[8898]: TcpListenerManager: not listening on [::1]::5900: bind: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

The listening address is invalid.  The port should be separated from the address with a single `:`, not the double `::` used as abbreviations in IPv6 addresses.

Wherever you have configured `[::1]::5900`, change to `[::1]:5900`

Answer (score 0):

I had disabled ipv6 and was seeing the same problem with RealVnc, fixed by using  `-IpListenAddresses=0.0.0.0`

Make sure to remove `-localhost` from parameter

Here is the parameter details

> IpListenAddresses - Comma-separated list of IP addresses on which to listen
> for TCP/UDP connections, or empty to listen on all available
> IP addresses. Note this parameter is ignored if the
> localhost parameter is set to True. (default=)